# Bootstrap's adaptive grid. Exit col

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

On lg it should be like:

[image]

On md it should be like:

[image]

Is any way to do this? Hidden and visible is not good idea, because `div3` is complicated control.

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish the lg layout, you can use the native [column order manipulation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) in Bootstrap (`*-push` and `*-pull` classes).

This is the idea: you put the highest column first (DIV2), the other ones next to it, and then "invert" the column order.

To make DIV3 slip away, understand that DIV1 and DIV2 are the same in both resolutions. So you only have to specify a different col size for DIV3 in md, in this case 12 which is full width. As it is more than the available space, it will go down.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6" style="height:600px">
            DIV2
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6" style="height:300px">
            DIV1
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-pull-6 col-md-12" style="height:300px">
            DIV3
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

See demo here: http://www.bootply.com/G0I9Lpg5AQ

Comment: Nicely done! I was tinkering with the classes earlier and didn't have much luck. Since no one else had given an answer I supplied a jQuery work-around. This is definitely the way to go.

Comment: It works perfectly fine even if DIV1 and DIV2 have different width, but if DIV2 is always higher then DIV1. But it don't have to. But thanks a lot, it's progress.

Comment: But you did not include that detail in the original question. You should, since everyone could help you better.

Then, if I understand right, you want to keep the same behaviour even in the case where DIV1 is higher than DIV2?

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes, you're right. DIV3 in lg always should be under DIV1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive, but I don't think you can do this with **ONLY** Bootstrap classes. With a bit of jQuery, though, you can pull it off.

[Here is a Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18781/)

**NOTE** - If you are not using Bootstrap's original `lg`, you will need to modify the `1200` to fit your version.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col1">
            <div class="col-xs-12 div1"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 div3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col2">
            <div class="col-xs-12 div2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row div3-row hidden-lg"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    var windowSize = $(this).width();
    if(windowSize < 1200) {
        $('.div3').appendTo('.div3-row');
    } else {
        $('.div3').appendTo('.col1');
    }
});
```